# How to list files without directories with specific time

Tags: grep, find

I want to list all my files starting from my home directory thats created or updated in last 10 hours.

```
ls -l | find /home/$user -mmin -600 | grep -v '^d'
```

I tried this but it's give me wrong result.

Comment: What results are you getting?  Also, it should be `$USER` and not `$user`.  You could also replace `/home/$USER` with just `~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `ls -l`. Your line should be for example if you want files which are at max 600 minutes old:

```
find /home/$USER -mmin -600 | grep -v '^d'
```

not sure why you want to leave out all files beginning with d but thats your thing to know. if you hoever want to search for directories your command should be:

```
find /home/$USER -type d -mmin -600
```

and if you simply want only all files changed in this time:

```
find /home/$USER -type f -mmin -600
```

From [manpage for the `find` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/find)

> -mmin n
>
> ```
>    File's data was last modified n minutes ago
> ```
>
> Numeric arguments can be specified as
>
> ```
>    +n     for greater than n,
>
>    -n     for less than n,
>
>    n      for exactly n.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

use `-not -type d` instead of `grep -v '^d'`

```
find /home/$USER -mmin -600 -not -type d
```

or simply `-type f`

Comment: `-not -type d` is superfluous, use `-type f` instead

Comment: @Videonauth you are right. i edited my post.